# Android Fragment Tab compilation error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I got a very odd problem. I need to create a three tabs in my activiy. Eveything seems fine, but I got the only ine mistake on the same line everytime no matter is it a part if the code either a comment. Here is the code

```
package com.example.i.actionbar4;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
//    start
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
//    end
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        start
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
// Error always there      mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1", null),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2", null),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3", null),
FragmentTab.class, null);
}
    //end
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Please post the log error messages.

Comment: Are you missing `mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);`?

Comment: Oops, my bad! Here is the error:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TabHost cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
            at com.example.i.actionbar4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)